# How to find out where the alert is raised from?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, browser

I'm just curious to know
Is there ANY ways in ANY browser to find out where the alert I get is raised from?

I tried it in chrome but there is no call stack available when alert shows.

Any idea?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638249/debug-js-code-which-triggers-an-alert

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can overwrite `alert`, and create an `Error` for the stack trace:

```
var old = alert;

alert = function() {
  console.log(new Error().stack);
  old.apply(window, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Thank!! I never thought alert is a member of window!

Comment: It can also be handy to replace the console.log statement with a debugger statement so you get dropped into the debugger at the point where alert was called.

Comment: i can't thank you enough for this. i got an old website with lots of issues. One of them was XSS all over the place. so i set one value to `<script>alert('XSS!');</script>` then there was the nightmare to locate all the places that string was evaluated, and alerts were poping up . Your answer was extremely helpfull. Now let me hold my breath and go back to that cesspool.

Comment: Thanks, this answer extremely helped to diagnose the very critical problem.

Comment: This is one of the neatest tricks I've ever seen. I would give this "StackOverflow gold" if I could (like reddit gold). Thanks a ton.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can monkeypatch the alert to do so:

```
//put this at the very top of your page:
window.alert = function() { throw("alert called") }
```

Answer (score 6):

How about wrapping the `alert`?

```
window.original_alert = alert;
alert = function (text) {
    // check the stack trace here
    do_some_debugging_or_whatever();

    // call the original function
    original_alert(text);
}
```

This should be cross-browser.

Answer (score 4):

There is a trace function is console is provided by all major browsers. 
***console.trace();***

With Proxy approach, as described in earlier answers, and console.trace(), we can print the entire stack with line number in console itself.

```js
(function(proxied) {
  window.alert = function() {
 console.trace();
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(window.alert);
```

This is an IIFE. Every alert call will have its trace printed in the console.