# Javascript automatically alerts when successfully adding a record to database (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, alert

I'm building out a simple chat app and every time I hit the send button (which adds a record to the database) I get an alert saying "Success". Nowhere in my code do I tell it to give me a success alert, only an error alert. Here is the code that gets called when the send button is clicked

```
function formCheck(e){
e.preventDefault();
// ensure message has text
if(msg.value.trim() != ""){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../handle_message.php',
        data: {
            name: name,
            color: color,
            msg: $( "#msg" ).val(),
        },
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success: function(bool){
            if (bool == "failure") {
                alert("Failure Inside Success function");
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failure, could not send message");
        },
    });
}
}
```

The php:

```
require_once("Database.php");
$dbc = $conn->getConnection();

$sql = "INSERT INTO Table (name, color, msg) VALUES (:name, :color, :msg)";
$statement = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":name", $_POST['name']);
$statement->bindValue(":color", $_POST['color']);
$statement->bindValue(":msg", $_POST['msg']);
$result = $statement->execute();

if(!$result){
    echo "failure";
}
```

The php works how it's supposed to. I'm just not sure why I'm getting the success popup after clicking the button. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I was only testing this in Google Chrome. Once I switched over to Firefox the alert went away, I guess it was something with chrome?

Going back to the Google Chrome tab, holding the shift key and pressing refresh did the trick! thanks to all that took the time to comment

Comment: search by that text in your project

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808665/how-to-find-out-where-the-alert-is-raised-from - I had a similar problem recently and this helped me trace it. It's especially hard if you might have some package code or something not yours raising the alert.

Comment: @brk Just checked both "success" and "alert" and found nothing. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Did you have a success alert in the past? ... if so try refreshing the brower while holding down the `Shift` key - or closing and reopening the browser window.

Comment: @traktor53 So the shift key worked? Would you mind explaining what holding shift and refreshing does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shift Reload**

Holding the shift key down when requesting a refresh tells the browser to reload everything from the server without using cached copies. When viewing pages which use the `file://` protocol it should ensure page files are reloaded from local storage rather than (say) history snapshots, but if  problems persist close and re-open the browser.

I probably learned of this in Netscape documentation last century - where it's documented now would require time and a more intensive search than the one I tried.

---

FWIW Technical details about headers sent to the server are covered in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/333488https://superuser.com/a/333488) on Super User.